# Adding consecutive numbering with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to find a formula to help me auto assign a unique reference number for each instance using multiple criteria.
[See image below...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu7mf.png)

[image]

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This will build your desired ID:

```
=IF(B2="None","None",IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,B2,$C$1:C1,C2)<>0,B2&TEXT(--RIGHT(C2,2),"000")&"-"&TEXT(AGGREGATE(14,6,--RIGHT($D$1:D1,3)/(($B$1:B2=B2)*($C$1:C1=C2)),1)+1,"000"),B2&TEXT(--RIGHT(C2,2),"000")&"-001"))
```

[image]